# Print the days of a month in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, days

I want to print all the days of a given month in Crystal Report. This is what my Crystal Report looks like:

[image: sample]

So on and so forth.

What I have done is, I created a table with dates, when the user pick a month through the date-timepicker my program will insert all the days of the picked month to the table.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Days in  {April} Or days in <> ?? Can you add an example?

Comment: have a look at this... http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=159 & this: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=4395

Comment: thank you sir for your reply...what I want sir is to print the days(in number form) of a month(which is from the parameter field) vertically sir...

Comment: thank you for the link sir but it is not what i want...i already have a formula for determining how many days in a month...what i want sir is to print it vertically...

Comment: Still not clear. Can you update your question please as to what you expect. From what I understand, you want number of days in column, so 30 rows for months having 30 days and 31 rows for months having 31 days. Right? And dont call me sir..

Comment: right yes thats right....

Comment: How does your result set look? I mean what results does your query return.

Comment: i have a formula(@days) which is this

whileprintingrecords;
numbervar x;
x := x + 1;

then in my details section expert i added a formula to new page which is

if remainder(@days,@daysinmonth)=0 then
true
else
false

but when i preview it all i see is 1...

Comment: It seems you want to show summary for each day in a month. If your data source contains a date field then why not get the day of that date field. If not then edit your question to include your data source/structure for the report.

Comment: the date field does not contain all the days in a month that's why I am struggling now....

Comment: Can you update your datasource? With a query

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do it in the query itself and get your query to return all days in the month. And for those days that dont have a value send back as 0. Then you can easily group by day and get your results automatically without having to do much in the report.

Comment: Have a look at this link. This is what I mean: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1225806-1292-1.aspx

Comment: thanks a bunch aMazing...I finally displayed all the days of the month now my problem is the daily total sales of sales and expenses...

Answer (score 0):

Although it can be attempted at SQL level also (as suggested by @aMazing), if you want to do it at Crystal Report level only, you can adapt from the following basic idea to accomplish rows with dates having no records.

Create three formula fields in report design, namely `First_Dates`, `Mid_Dates`, `Last_Dates` and set their values in formula editor as under:

1. First_Dates

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   numberVar TotalDays := Day ({Sale_Date_Field}) - 1;
   numberVar i;
   stringVar DayList := "";
   for i := 1 to TotalDays step 1 do 
       DayList := DayList & ToText(i, 0) & "          0.00          0.00" & Chr(13);
   DayList;
   ```
2. Mid_Dates

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   numberVar FromDay := Day({Sale_Date_Field}) + 1;
   numberVar To_Day := Day(Next({Sale_Date_Field})) - 1;
   numberVar i;
   stringVar DayList := "";
   for i := FromDay to To_Day step 1 do
   DayList := DayList & ToText(i, 0) & "          0.00          0.00" & Chr(13);
   DayList;
   ```
3. Last_Dates

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   numberVar NextDay := Day ({Sale_Date_Field}) + 1;
   numberVar i;
   numberVar MonthDays := 30;
   if (Month ({Sale_Date_Field}) in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]) then
       MonthDays := 31
   else if (Month ({Sale_Date_Field}) in [4,6,9,11]) then
       MonthDays := 30
   else if (Month ({Sale_Date_Field}) = 2
     and Remainder(Year({Sale_Date_Field}), 4) = 0) then
       MonthDays := 29
   else
       MonthDays := 28;
   stringVar DayList := "";
   for i := NextDay to MonthDays step 1 do
       DayList := DayList & ToText(i, 0) & "          0.00          0.00" & Chr(13);
   DayList;
   ```

Now place these formula fields in your report as under:

1. `First_Dates` in *Report Header* Section
2. `Mid_Dates` in *Details **b*** Section
3. `Last_Dates` in *Report Footer* Section

Now enable `Can Grow` option for each of them in the `Format Field` on the `Common` tab.
Enable `Suppress Blank Section` option for *Detail b* Section in Section Expert.
Format the fields and `DayList` accordingly.
For multiple months the report can be grouped by Months and `First_Dates`, `Last_Dates` formulas can be placed in the Group Header and Footer respectively.

*This solution will not work with Cross-Tab format*.